# Program that "mean" a parse tree in Prolog, don't work

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am studying **DCG grammar** and **parse tree** using the Ivan Bratko book: Programming fro Artificial Intelligence.

On the book I found the following example that show a DCG grammar that also generate a parse tree and a **meaning/2** predicate that is used to mean the position after some moves.

This is the code:

```
move(move(Step)) --> step(Step).
move(move(Step, Move)) --> step(Step), move(Move).

step(step(up)) --> [up].
step(step(down)) --> [down].

meaning(move(Step, Move), Dist):- meaning(Step, D1),
                      meaning(Move, D2),
                      Dist is (D1 + D2).

meaning(step(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).

meaning(step(up), 1).

meaning(step(down), -1).
```

On the book show the following query with the following output:

```
move(Tree, [up,up,down, up, up], []), meaning(Tree, Dist).
Tree = move(step(up), move(step(up), move(step(down), move(step(up), move(step(up)))))),
Dist = 3
```

The problem is that if I try to execute the previous query, I always obtain FALSE (I obtain false with whatever query...)

```
?- move(Tree, [up,up,down, up, up], []), meaning(Tree, Dist).
false.
```

Why? What is wrong? What ma I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second clause of `meaning/2` is wrong. It should be:

```
meaning(move(Step), Dist):- meaning(Step, Dist).
```

To pinpoint this error you could have tried with a single move:

```
?- move(Tree, [up], []).
Tree = move(step(up))
```

So there has to be a base case in `meaning/2` that deals with a single move, and inspecting your code it should be precisely the second clause.

In fact, every list of moves ends with one of this kind of terms, `move(step(X))` with `X` in {up, down}.